# Is there a sequence in these numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a sequence in these numbers?(separated by commas)

```
1,16,81,625
```

It must be the same equation to get the next number.
For example, it must include a variable,(x) and be able to continuously get to the next number

Comment: There are infinitely many sequence which start out with this sequence of numbers, but I assume that they are taking $x^4$.

Comment: Starting with $1,2,3,5$, the OEIS gives $3329$ possible sequences. Pick your preferred one. And these are only the sequences stored in OEIS, of course there are infinitely many possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

$$F_n^4$$

(Fibonacci) starting from $n=2$.

The next one is $4096$.

---

Unless it's the fourth power of this sequence https://oeis.org/A062167, starting from the fourth term.

Then the next is $707281$.

Comment: @Alex: why should I ? (Not counting that this is a perfectly uncalled-for request.)

Comment: @Alex I don't see what's rude in taking the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following sequence: $$1^4, 2^4, 3^4, 5^4, 7^4,...$$

Comment: Mh, $1$ is not considered a prime.